# How to convert a byte array to an integer in C?

Tags: c, arrays, int, byte

I have a payload from a client which is a byte* and contains always an integer.
I need the value of the payload as an integer. How can I convert this?

```
byte* payload
```

to

```
int value
```

Comment: In what form is the integer in your byte array ? Binary or text ? If binary, is it known to be of the correct endianness ?

Comment: the integer is in text form

Comment: And is it null-terminated? If it is, then you're dealing with a string and normal conversion rules apply